# How suspend process flow until specified Event is fired? WebBrowserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, webbrowser-control

my question is how to `await LoadCompletedEvent()` when i perform a `WebBrowser.Navigate()`.

I want a simple WebBrowserControl in my WPF App, imagine the Browser and a Button, and on `Button.Click()` I want my `WebBrowser` to Navigate to specified URL perform a Login with one User, then Logout of the Webside and Login with another User.
This I want to perform at least 10 or 100 times, I don't mind.

When I have my `ButtonClickEvent` there will go all my necesary code to execute my loop and everything, but when I execute the `WebBrowser.Navigate()`, in or in subprocess of `ButtonClickEvent`, it wont navigate anywhere until the Event totally finished. Example:

```
    private ButtonClickEvent( object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.Navigate(URL);
        this.wait() //-> some type of waiting for WebBrowser.LoadCompleteEvent
        browser.FindElementByID("User").Text = "abc";

     }

     private async void wait()
     {
        await NavigateAsync(URL);
     }

     public static Task NavigateAsync(string url)
     {
      .....
     }
```

*Just PseuodoCode*

The text input wont be executed, instead will give an error because the Browser still not navigate to the URL.

I tried to update the UI with an asynchronous Thread which supose to update the UI... Nothing, the UI doesn't move a bit.
The WebBrowserControl is Asynchronous, so how can I await asynchronously the LoadCompletedEvent with `Async Await`?
I tried to navigate from a thread to the URL, and with a simple loop and Bool Var I waited for the LoadCompletedEvent but it is never thrown. Of course I tried different Priorities on `Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke()` but also without any satisfying result.
I also tried `Semaphore` in the `LoadCompletedEvenet` with also no result.
All this seems to be synchronous Eventhandling...

Some Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `await` anything by using a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
private Task NavigateAsync(string url)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  LoadCompletedEventHandler subscription = null;
  subscription = (_, __) =>
  {
    browser.LoadCompleted -= subscription;
    tcs.TrySetResult(null);
  };
  browser.LoadCompleted += subscription;
  browser.Navigate(url);
  return tcs.Task;
}

private async void ButtonClickEvent( object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await NavigateAsync(URL);
  browser.FindElementByID("User").Text = "abc";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but I also tried to declare a `private async Event()` it throws me and compile Error, so with which library you can declare a Event as `async` like you do in your example?

Comment: how would you do that the `Task NavigateAsync` could be in another class?

Comment: @user3167232: I would make `NavigateAsync` an extension method on `WebBrowser`.

Comment: But the thing is that synchronous code will continue processing. So your solution is very good, but if i leave Button_Click Event synchronous and call a asynchrounous Method the Button_Click wont await nothing and continous. I will modify my question for better understanding

Comment: @user3167232: You'll need to make your button click event handler asynchronous, as in my code example.

Comment: Thanks, is what I espected, so i will make a completely asynchronous app.